# Find the Direction travelled using Source and Destination (latitude & longtitude)

Tags: c#, javascript

I have two points say Source=(lat1,lon1) and destination=(lat2,lat3)

I want to know which way the source traveled,

ex: from NorthWest to Southeast (or)
    SouthWest to Northeast etc....

Can any one help..

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Haversine forumla. See a worked example (using JavaScript) [on this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). You can find out [more about Haversine via Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).